# PHP Email Form not sending mail with PostFix installed

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04

I have a very basic email form on my website, www.waldoswall.com that I am building as a portfolio piece. I am having issues getting the mail form to send mail to my email address. I found a tutorial and installed PostFix as per the instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04

I am not certain if it is an issue with how I set up the server (I host from rackspace and try to set up everything myself based on tutorials and my personal knowledge.) or a problem with my php code. I have read a few places that I should check the php log and am confused as to where I might find this file on the server to take a closer look. For now I'll post my code in case something is obviously wrong.

```
    <form method="POST" action="verify.php">
        <div id="formContent">
        <div id="formLeft">
        <h3>Name:</h3><br /><input class="whitebg" name="name" type="text"><br /><br />
        <h3>Email:</h3><br /><input class="whitebg" name="email" type="email"><br /><br />
        <h3>Phone:</h3><br /><input class="whitebg" name="tel" type="tel"><br /><br />

        </div>
        <div id="formRight">
            <div style="clear:both;"><h3>Message:</h3><br /><textarea class="whitebg" cols="50" name="message"></textarea><br /><br /></div>


        </div>

        </div>
        <div id="formBottom">
        <?php
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $publickey = "6LegNOkSAAAAADFzJsNJtYMJc8bpDMMPY9pm4lBb"; // you got this from the signup page
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <p><input style="margin-top:25px;" class="whitebg" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The verify php file contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Home - Kevin Waldmann</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topSpace"><h1>Waldos Wall</h1></div>
<div style="padding:25px;" class="contentPane" id="slideVerify">
        <div id="goHomeBg">
        <div class="navItem unselectable" id="goHome" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.waldoswall.com';">Go Home</div>        
 <?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "6LegNOkSAAAAACO0vWlqLWRZTkkpntcAM3IHHiaw";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                          $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                          $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                          $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
   "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
$to = "kjwaldmann@gmail.com";
$subject = "Waldos Wall Contact Form";
$message = "Hello Kevin!<br/>" . "Name:" . $_REQUEST["name"]. "\r\n" . "Email:" .$_REQUEST["email"] . "\r\n" . "Telephone:" . $_REQUEST["tel"] . "\r\n" . "Message:" .$_REQUEST["message"];
$from = $_REQUEST["email"];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Message Sent.";
}
?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **seriously** recommend using [Pear's Net_SMTP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP) for mail, I use it on my server and it works like a charm!!

Also, if you don't want to use that... change $_REQUEST to $_POST as it is known to be better.

Comment: Okay so I installed pear, "sudo apt-get install php-pear" and then ran "pear install Net_SMTP" is there anything else configuration wise I'll need to do in order to get it working?

Comment: You'll need to find out how to use it... it's fairly simple to use. :)
It runs through SMTP, this will allow you to either use your own SMTP server or I can supply you with one(for $5/m), or you can get it free from GMAIL.

Answer (score 0):

I get that you're not seeing any errors are you?

I'd check the logs first. Go ahead and try to send an email right from your ssh console and check your mail logs in /var/log/

If there are any errors post them